# JNI Error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method

Tags: c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Error Message : `Pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError thrown by 'void com.exampleTest.NDKT.I(android.app.Activity):-2'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method "Lcom/exampleTest/NDKT;.PN()Ljava/lang/String;"`

I should try ndk c++ call java method because i want you java method thought android package name know

i tried below

- java call method String -> void change
  => c++ : jmethodID jMethod = pE->GetStaticMethodID(jClass, "GO", "()V");
- java code "this" -> "MainActivity.this"

## - Java code

```
CallNDK class{

public static void initialize(final Activity a,final SIMECB cb) {

System.loadLibrary("simpleinit"); 
_CB = cb;
_INSTANCE = new CallNDK();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
      _INSTANCE.I(a);
}
}).start();

}
}
==> initialize () -> Activity = MainActivity.this
```

## - NDK

### CallNDK.cpp

```
static string mPN; //Packege Name

#ifdef __ANDROID__
void CallNDK::I(JNIEnv* pE, jobject pA){
  // Package Name Method call
  CHECK::PN(pE, mPN);
}
```

### CHECK.h

```
#ifndef CHECK_H_
#define CHECK_H_

#ifdef __ANDROID__
#include <jni.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

class CHECK {
public:
#ifdef __ANDROID__

static void PN(
JNIEnv* pE,
string& pO);


#endif
};

#endif
```

### CHECK.cpp

```
#include "CHECK.h"
#ifdef __ANDROID__
#include <jni.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

#ifdef __ANDROID__

void CHECK::PN(JNIEnv* pE, string& pO){

jclass classes = pE->FindClass("com/exampleTest/NDKT");
jmethodID jMethod = pE->GetMethodID(classes, "SimpleMethod", ()Ljava/lang/String;");

if(!jMethod) {
    CALLUtil::LOG("class loader method access");
    return;
}
jstring jsResult = (jstring)pE->CallStaticObjectMethod(jClass, jMethod);
const char* cResult = pE->GetStringUTFChars(jsResult, NULL);
std::string sResult(cResult);
pO = sResult;

}
```

## - NDK of call java class code

```
enter code here
NDKT Class {
private static int _MAX_TRY_INVOKE_COUNT = 5;

public static String SimpleMethod(Activity a){

for(int i = 0; i < _MAX_TRY_INVOKE_COUNT; i++) {
try {
return a.getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
} catch (Exception e) {
try { Thread.sleep(50); } catch (Exception e2) { }
}
}
return ""
}
}
```

- Error 
  JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION:

`JNI FindClass called with pending exception 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError' thrown in void com.exampleTest.CallNDK.I(android.app.Activity):-2 in call to FindClass from void com.exampleText.CallNDK.I(android.app.Activity)`

`Pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError thrown by 'void com.exampleTest.NDKT.I(android.app.Activity):-2'
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method "Lcom/exampleTest/NDKT;.PN()Ljava/lang/String;"`

Comment: Please, provide a description.

Comment: Writing code to get Android package name from ndk code.
An error occurred at this time: "jClass, "SimpleMethod," "(Ljava/lang/String;") failed to find the method.

Comment: Your code for CHECK.cpp is malformed and will not compile.  Please be sure to present a *bona fide* [mre] so that we can be sure to address whatever issues actually exist.

Comment: Also, you have C++ code there, but no C that I see.  Tags edited.

Comment: That last piece of Java code also appears to be broken. The `class` keyword is in the wrong place, and is incorrecly capitalized. Also, in the code the method is named `SimpleMethod`, but the error message refers to something named `GPN`. Please edit your question and copy-paste the actual code that you're running.

Comment: And now you've fixed that, `SimpleMethod()` takes an `Activity` parameter but you're searching for it with a `String` parameter. Is this the real code?

Comment: yes, real code 
because, i want to android project package name return NDK code

Comment: This can't possibly be your real code, since some of the code you've posted contains syntactic errors that would prevent it from even compiling.

Comment: i'm success SimpleMethod() parameter changed thank you "user207421"